# Error: You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE  
FROM wp_postmeta  
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT ID  
    FROM wp_posts  
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_parent IN (
        SELECT post_id
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE meta_value = 'mycbgenie'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is:

```sql
DELETE
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `post_id` IN (
  SELECT `id`
  FROM `wp_posts`
  WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment' AND `post_parent` IN (
    SELECT `der`.`post_id`
    FROM (SELECT `post_id`
          FROM `wp_postmeta`
          WHERE `meta_value` = 'mycbgenie') `der`
  )
);
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fddcb/1)</kbd>

Comment: I think you need to add "AS" before 'der'

Comment: @JamesHayes: `AS` is optional. `SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...` `The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM clause must have a name.` - [13.2.10.8 Subqueries in the FROM Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).